# How to read string property in json objet

Tags: node.js

I have this body request i need to manipulate:

```js
{
  "event" : "message",
  "token" : "957fa13859e06b22b96060ab97df934e5aec0ca02c432",
  "uid" : "",
  "contact[uid]" : "",
  "contact[name]" : "",
  "contact[type]": "user",
  "message[dtm]": "1530022083",
  "message[uid]": "87FA901709E3C05CCB0270B6B3C893AF",
  "message[cuid]": "",
  "message[dir]" : "i",
  "message[type]" : "chat",
  "message[body][text]" : "",
  "message[ack]": "3" 
}
```

how can a read properties with []? when it is converted to json objetc, properties with [] is a string, like this:

```js
{ event: 'message',
  token: '957fa13859e06b22b96060ab97df934e5aec0ca02c432',
  uid: '',
  'contact[uid]': '',
  'contact[name]': '',
  'contact[type]': 'user',
  'message[dtm]': '1530022083',
  'message[uid]': '87FA901709E3C05CCB0270B6B3C893AF',
  'message[cuid]': '',
  'message[dir]': 'i',
  'message[type]': 'chat',
  'message[body][text]': '',
  'message[ack]': '3' }
```

any ideas how can i get data?

Kind regards

Comment: This is a weird mix of JSON and querystring. Normally if the request is "Content-Type: application/json" you should send `{{contact:{uid: '', name: '', type: 'user'}, message:{dtm: '...', uid: '...', cuid: '...'}}` or if it's querystring you have `contact[uid]=''&contact[name]='` I think your problem here is when you converted a querystring to a JSON, you didn't do it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I see what happened here,

You have used a function to convert a querystring to JSON but the function you used only works with flat querystrings (no nested variables).

Since you're using Node.JS you should try [NPM Package `qs`](https://github.com/ljharb/qs)

It takes a querystring like this :

`event=message&token=957fa13859e06b22b96060ab97df934e5aec0ca02c432&uid=&contact[uid]=&contact[name]=&contact[type]=user&message[dtm]=1530022083&message[uid]=87FA901709E3C05CCB0270B6B3C893AF&message[cuid]=&message[dir]=i&message[type]=chat&message[body][text]=&message[ack]=3`

And makes a JSON object like this :

```
{
    event: 'message',
    token: '957fa13859e06b22b96060ab97df934e5aec0ca02c432',
    uid: '',
    contact: { uid: '', name: '', type: 'user' },
    message: {
        dtm: '1530022083',
        uid: '87FA901709E3C05CCB0270B6B3C893AF',
        cuid: '',
        dir: 'i',
        type: 'chat',
        body: {
            text: ''
        },
        ack: '3'
    }
}
```

with just the following code :

```
const qs = require("qs");

let querystring = "event=message&token=957fa13859e06b22b96060ab97df934e5aec0ca02c432&uid=&contact[uid]=&contact[name]=&contact[type]=user&message[dtm]=1530022083&message[uid]=87FA901709E3C05CCB0270B6B3C893AF&message[cuid]=&message[dir]=i&message[type]=chat&message[body][text]=&message[ack]=3";
let JSONquery = qs.parse(querystring);

console.log(JSONquery);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It works! thank you for your help. I knew it had to be something very simple. I apprecite a lot you help. have a nice day

Comment: Good to know ^^, good day to you too. And don't forget to mark the answer as solving your issue so that people with the same problem can benefit from it too.